# $f : \omega \to \omega$ unbounded on every ultrafilter element, must $f$ be strictly increasing some ultrafilter element?

Tags: filters

Consider an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ and $f : \omega \to \omega$ such that
$f|_{S}$ is unbounded for every $S \in \mathcal{U}$. Must there exist
$S \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $f|_{S}$ is strictly increasing?

My classmates and I believe this is false. This is false for proper filters in general. For example: the collection of sets which contain sets of the form $k\cdot{}\omega$ as subsets, $k > 0$, and the function $f$ mapping $n!$ to $n$ and otherwise mapping to $0$.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308489/peculiar-question-on-unlimited-hypernaturals

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that your question is tantamount to whether or not any function which is dominated (modulo the ultrafilter) by the identity function is constant. In that case, the answer is negative since that would require $\omega^\omega/\cal U$ to be well-ordered, which is impossible if $\cal U$ is not principal. Or rather, it means that the answer is positive and $S$ is some finite set.

Comment: (The language and exact details of the question in that post are slightly different, but my answer there also answers your question.  Specifically, such an $S$ need not exist if $\mathcal{U}$ is an arbitrary ultrafilter, and it is independent of ZFC whether there exists an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ for which such an $S$ must always exist.)